# Best method to transfer large continuous data

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am beginning to write an app that sends data from the app to computer software via a wifi connection. There is a lot of data needed to be sent. Ie. Microphone input.  The software needs to be able to tell if their is noise going into the microphone, and could be extended to indicate noise levels.

However I have thought of two ways to transfer the data.

1. Send all the data outright continuously and then let the computer software handle it. The pros of this is that if I want to make changes to how the data is interpret I only have to update the computer software and not the mobile app. The cons being I have to send a lot of data for a simple on/off state.
2. Send only the states (there is noise/there isn't). The pros of this is that the data transfer will be heavily reduced and can be sent only when there is a state change. The cons now being in order to update the software I must update the app too.

I am concerned about mismatches in app/software versions causing problems for users, but also concerned of large data transfer.

Which method is best to use? Is there another method I have not considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting question. There is the third way: encode the audio signal in the app and decode it on computer. It adds computational complexity but saves lots of bandwidth. The overall power consumption may be reduced - I don't know.

Considering the compatibility issue, I prefer the 1st or the 3rd way.

Comment: Thanks, 3 is like a hybrid between the two methods. I'll see how it works in practice.